# Render <%= %> as a String in an .html.erb View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to print following as a string in my `.html.erb` view.

```
<%= selected_color %>
```

So, I tried following in my file:

```
<h3><%= '<%= selected_color %>' %></h3>
```

It gave me following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting ')'
```

If I remove `<%= '<%= selected_color %>' %>` and place some string like `abc`, then it is printed on page without any issue.

As it is static page, I don't want to create a controller for it. So, can you help in showing that string on page?

**p.s.** I'm using ruby v1.9.3 and rails v3.1.0

Comment: Do you want to print the value of `selected_color`, or just the text?

Comment: just the static text within `<%= %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should double the `%` symbols as follow:

```
<h3><%%= rating_color %></h3>
```

#### Edit for source:

In [erb.rb line 50](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L50), we see that `<%%` is a special tag that is replaced by `<%` we can also see that on line [650](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L650).

Comment: Awesome!! It works.. But what does `%%` do? If you can edit answer and help me in understanding significance of double `%`, I'll mark it as answer :)

Comment: From the erb source code [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L50) we can see that `<%%` is simply replaced by `<%`  (see also [this line](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb#L626))

Comment: @ex0ns please include that in your answer

Answer (score 3):

Pure HTML

`&lt;%= selected_color %&gt;`

or double % as mentioned by @ex0ns

`<%%= selected_color %>`